# Convert xml document (Guidewire Product Model file) to comma delimited csv file

Tags: guidewire

Need some assistance converting an xml document to a CSV file using an xslt stylesheet. Basically I'm looking forward to something like this at bare minimum to be the output:

Coverage Name 1, Coverage Pattern Code 1

Coverage Name 2, Coverage Pattern Code 2

The xml file would be like this:

```
                <ns0:Entry>
                                    <ns1:Code>PALiabCond</ns1:Code>
                                    <ns1:Names>
                                        <ns1:Entry>
                                            <ns1:Locale>en_CA</ns1:Locale>
                                            <ns1:Value>Personal Auto Liability Conditions</ns1:Value>
                                        </ns1:Entry>
                                        <ns1:Entry>
                                            <ns1:Locale>fr_CA</ns1:Locale>
                                            <ns1:Value>Responsabilité auto personnelle - Conditions</ns1:Value>
                                        </ns1:Entry>
                                        <ns1:Entry>
                                            <ns1:Locale>en_US</ns1:Locale>
                                            <ns1:Value>Personal Auto Liability Conditions</ns1:Value>
                                        </ns1:Entry>
                                    </ns1:Names>
                                    <ns1:Priority>1</ns1:Priority>
                                </ns0:Entry>
```

Where 'Coverage Name' would be the node 'ns1:Value' and 'Coverage Pattern Code' would be 'ns1:Code'. Is there some easy way to get this done by using XLST?

Regards,
Matías

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any number of tools to do this not just XSLT.

> e.g. a very quick Groovy script using XMLSlurper will also do it

But I am wondering why you are wanting to do it. If it's for importing then I don't believe that you can easily import these items anyway as they are key to the product model and underlying architecture that the system relies upon.